# AngularJS and ui-grid: how to resize grid height to fill the remaining space

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have this ui-grid containing a random number of rows, but sure thing, it contains a great number of columns.

That said, I have a someway responsive-related problem: I want the grid to fill the remaining space of the page, in both width and height.

Apart from look-and-feel reasoning, the logic behind this is, on large screen devices, to allow the user to look at as much columns as possible and to extend the ui-grid height to the bottom, even if there are few rows displayed (btw, the page has no footer).

So, using a media query, I set `width: 100%` to the grid and manage to do the first part of the trick, but I'm struggling for the second part: the height.

I can't really make the `gridWrapper` height to expand the grid to the bottom, even if his width behaves correctly, without using Bootstrap but... the [css struggle](http://plnkr.co/edit/JNaooWxdKftHja9BKdVQ) is real.

So I managed to have something near to what I want, but:

- it's a ridicoulusly complicated, weak and un-reusable solution;
- the row selection icon layout (the one on the left side of the rows) messes up as the row number grows, and i can't get rid of the selection feature by now;
- the height of the grid is greater than the height of the page. I could set it to 90% instead of 100% to make it work... close, but not responsive, still.

Even if this scenario is the subject of [many](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2652) [issues](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/3031) on the GitHub of the project, I'm asking you:

> Is there a way to obtain what I want in a responsive, maybe bootstrap-inclusive way before I delve in a swamp made of `display: table;`, `display: flex;` & Co.?

Comment: The following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SuP6oyR9lPD0r1gR3StG) shows what exactly what I want to achieve, but the point of my question is wheter there's a Bootstrap and responsive way to accomplish it or not.

Answer (score 2):

give grid height: auto either in css or once grid is ready i mean once you have assigned array to gridOptions.data after that

```
$(".ui-grid").css("height", "auto");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am affraid that only way how to achieve this is use of JS and setting css height and width programatically.

You have to set it when:

- grid is created
- window size changes